# Sublime Pylint PyQt4 Module has no member

Tags: pyqt4, sublimetext3, pylint

I'm using Sublime-Text3 with SublimeLinter + SublimeLinter-pylint installed.
Everything works as expected, except for pylint "scanning" PyQt4

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
```

works OK. Pylint detects QtCore and QtGui, but if

```
button = QtGui.QPushButton()
layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
```

pylint sets red underlines and tells that

> PyQt4.QtGui has no "QPushButton" member

Is there any way to fix this error or maybe ignore PyQt in SublimeLinter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, thanks to **sthenault**

Step by step.

1. Generate rc file

`pylint --generate-rcfile > pylint.rc`

2. Replace the line

`extension-pkg-whitelist=`

by

`extension-pkg-whitelist=PyQt4`

3. Sublime

> Preferences -> Package Settings -> SublimeLinter -> Settings - User

```
"pylint": {
            [..another settings..]
            "rcfile": "/path_to_rc/pylint.rc",
        }
```

Comment: Note: If you're not using Sublime and you just want to create a rc file and your search engine led you here, you'll probably want to call that rc file `pylintrc` rather than `pylint.rc` because otherwise pylint won't find it unless you pass it the name explicitly. This solution works because the path is passed in Sublime settings.

Answer (score 2):

recent versions of pylint don't load extensions modules anymore (i.e. compiled code not written in pure python), unless they are listed using the `extension-pkg-whitelist` option. This is because loading extensions modules requires to actually load the code which may trigger undesired side effects.

In your case, `pylint --extension-pkg-whitelist=PyQt4 <your module>` (or using equivalent entry in the config file) should fix your problem.

Comment: After reading your comment I've found the solution and now it works.